# HTTP unresolved pings - TCP Server

Tags: c#, http, server, tcp, client

Every 30 seconds my TCP Server receives a packet from my HTTP Client both coded in c#.
This is the console information:

```
94:39:38 - [ERROR] Unhandeled: ???
14:39:38 - [ERROR] fin: True | opcode: 9 | msglen: 0 | mask: True | arrayLength: 6
14:39:38 - [ERROR] hex: 8980d6bb0d39
14:39:38 - [ERROR] cast: System.Byte[]  
14:40:08 - [ERROR] Unhandeled: ??????
14:40:08 - [ERROR] fin: True | opcode: 9 | msglen: 0 | mask: True | arrayLength: 6
14:40:08 - [ERROR] hex: 8980ad8fd4e3
14:40:08 - [ERROR] cast: System.Byte[]
14:40:38 - [ERROR] Unhandeled: ???3
k
14:40:38 - [ERROR] fin: True | opcode: 9 | msglen: 0 | mask: True | arrayLength: 6
14:40:38 - [ERROR] hex: 8980e3330a6b
14:40:38 - [ERROR] cast: System.Byte[]
14:41:08 - [ERROR] Unhandeled: ??]???
14:41:08 - [ERROR] fin: True | opcode: 9 | msglen: 0 | mask: True | arrayLength: 6
14:41:08 - [ERROR] hex: 89805da8aec9
14:41:08 - [ERROR] cast: System.Byte[]
14:41:38 - [ERROR] Unhandeled: ?????
14:41:38 - [ERROR] fin: True | opcode: 9 | msglen: 0 | mask: True | arrayLength: 6
14:41:38 - [ERROR] hex: 8980bea007ed
14:41:38 - [ERROR] cast: System.Byte[]
14:42:08 - [ERROR] Unhandeled: ???|?_
14:42:08 - [ERROR] fin: True | opcode: 9 | msglen: 0 | mask: True | arrayLength: 6
14:42:08 - [ERROR] hex: 8980b67cd35f
14:42:08 - [ERROR] cast: System.Byte[]
```

This log is produced by the following code:

```
public void process(byte[] Data) {
     bool fin = (Data[0] & 0b10000000) != 0,
              mask = (Data[1] & 0b10000000) != 0;

     int opcode = Data[0] & 0b00001111, // expecting 1 - text message
     msglen = Data[1] - 128, // & 0111 1111
     offset = 2;

     if (msglen == 0)
     {
         log.Error($"Unhandeled: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Data)}");
         log.Error($"fin: {fin} | opcode: {opcode} | msglen: {msglen} | mask: {mask} | arrayLength: {Data.Length}");
         log.Error($"hex: {ByteArrayToHexString(Data)}");
         log.Error($"cast: {Data}");
         return null;
     }
}
```

After several of these probably pings the TCP Server won't be able to parse other packets send by the client, only these pings. Before any of these pings it's able to parse packets fine eventually, it won't anymore.
Does anyone know how to prevent these supposed pings or how to handle them so they do not freeze up that it will not parse any of my other requests??

EDIT: It also stops the pings from being processed, until a new connection is created. That connection works again until several pings.

Comment: The pings should not have any affect on the application code.   They are completely independent.  TCP there is no guarantee the a single sent message will be received in one chunk.  Also with TCP is it valid to receive an empty packet [if (msglen == 0]. You code is not robust and PING may be affecting the alignment/packing of receive messages, but is not the root cause of the issue.

Comment: Is there a way to see/prevent that it affects the alignment/packing of other messages?

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  TCP allows for splitting and combining datagrams (pieces of a message).  So sniffer shows what is entering the Ethernet Adaptor on a machine. But windows can also internally can split messages.  The pings are handle in the Ethernet card before windows so that is why I said the pings are not part of the send/receive data.